# getBean(Class<T> arg0) not working without type cast

Tags: java, spring

```
protected Object createJobInstance(TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception 
{
   Job job =  ctx.getBean(bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass());
}
```

Above piece of code not working without type cast..why type cast is required when input type to getBean is Class < T > and return type is T

Comment: Have you tried with `bundle.getJobDetail().getJobCleass().class`?

Comment: It works for me with v3.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: Also works for me, with `quartz-2.1.5`.

Comment: I tried quartz 1.8.6 and spring 3.0.5... dint work,then I tried quartz 2.1.5 as well still no luck...was trying to learn spring quartz integration from here by mavenizing it..but facing issues...http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/10/spring-and-quartz-integration-using.html

Answer (score 1):

The JVM probably can't tell from your code what the type of the bean is until runtime, so there is no way to compile it.  You either have to downcast here, or change the signature of your `getJobClass()` method (to return `Class<? extends Job>`).

Comment: return type is same as you suggested.. still not working ....   http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDetail.html

Comment: If that is the case then I suspect Job in your createJobInstance() is not org.quartz.Job.